# Setting layout parameters from Java with logic

Tags: android, android-layout

I know how to add Layout parameters from Java, but I need help in understanding what these numbers below are really for? Why exactly the same numbers needed?

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ((screenWidth * 20) / 450), ((screenHeight * 30) / 450));
```

Here `screenWidth` is obtained by `size.x` and similar for `screenHeight`.
Size is a Point object.

```
Point size = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size)
```

Why 20/450? and 30/450? How are they important? For screen ratio?

Does **450** mean anything?

Comment: Where did you get that bit of code?

Comment: From a game code. @Squonk Thank you

Comment: Then I can only assume the developer of that code had a specific reason to use those values for a particular layout. There's no reason those values are standard in all cases or that they'd even work for all screen sizes / densities.

Answer (score 0):

It's not always necessary to provide `((screenWidth * 20) / 450)` and `((screenHeight * 30) / 450)` as arguments in `LayoutParams`'s constructor. It takes width and height of the layout as arguments.
For more information, you can have look at official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#LinearLayout.LayoutParams%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: I am not asking about what the constructor takes. I just want to know for what reason, might those numbers been used.

Comment: That my friend, depends totally on where you copied this from. It might be his own logic to reach his own goal which may not be useful to us at all.

Comment: I just want to know about that logic.